# USB Debugging is disabled after update to android 4.2.2 (Samsung Note Tablet)

Tags: android, adb

I have Samsung Galaxy Note Tablet and after update to android 4.2.2 I can not check USB Debugging button. I see it, but can't check it and adb does not list my device, but otherwise I can browse the device, when it is plugged on USB. I updated SDK and driver and everything, but adb can't list my device and on my device I can't check the  USB Debugging button, because it is disabled, it's deemed. 
Three days I've been googling, but couldn't even find question similar to this issue. 
Could anyone suggest me a solution, please!
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on an Android support forum.

Comment: if you are talking about the original Note (i717) - I think the latest official update from Samsung was based on 4.1.2 Android. you should ask for help from the maker of your build.

Comment: @MattK - incorrect.  The question concerns uniquely-for-developers development tools rather than end-user functionality, and therefore belongs here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I believe it's up for discussion so let's see how the community feels. It sounds like a software bug caused by an upgrade and should be raised on the developers site (google Android forum).

Comment: @Matt , This is about a programming. The close reason reads:"...are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**..."

Comment: @JonasCz agree to disagree, you should vote it up and see if it gets an answer then

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if it would work but try this: Go to Settings->About Phone/Tablet and keep clicking on Build Number continuously. It enables developer options. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if my question has been unappropriated for the site, but thanks to MattK's comment I realized that the problem could be at the side of the manufacturer. So I contacted Samsung support center and they advised me to restore the fabric settings of the device. I did that (of course before archived my data with Kies) and now everything va bene